# using class as method in java

Tags: java

How do I use (if possible) a class as a method parameter in Java?

```
public class validators() {
    public int minLength(int l) {
        // do something
    } 
}

public class formField() {
    public void addField(String field, validators val) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following :

```
addField("username", new validators() { 
     minLength(6);
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: if you are calling it from same java file, shouldnt be a problem as already you have declared your method to be public. Also, please format and explain stuff correctly like where you are calling that thing from.

Comment: We can not use `validators()` as class name in Java.

Comment: Your example code is so far away from being compilable, I am not even sure what you're attempting to really do.

Comment: You can't have two public classes in the same source file. Also as @akhil_mittal have mentioned, the name `validators()` and `formField()` are not valid class names.

Comment: Also class name should start with capital: a very basic coding convention.

Comment: @akhil_mittal The code is for the example . Validators Are in diffrent class and file , indeed and There are Capital Letter on their name. I import the class as needed. I do wish to have help how to achive the goal of the question becuase eclipse does not allow me the set minLength value.

Comment: @user2439336 Have you got a constructor that sets the minimum length? If so, you should be able to do `addField("username", new Validators(6));`. Or perhaps a static factory method that returns an instance with the appropriate field set, such as `Validators.createMinLengthValidator(6)`?

Comment: It's not very clear, but I think what you want is an `interface` called `Validator`, and a number of classes that implement it (`ValidatorOne, ValidatorTwo` etc).  Then your `FormField` class can have `public void addField(String field, Validator val)` and you can pass it any object of any of the `ValidatorXXX`classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the current instance, you can use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure what are you trying to achieve yet the following code will compile fine:

```
public class Validators {
    public int minLength(int l) {
        // do something
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class FormField {
    public void addField(String field, Validators val) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And then we can use it as:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FormField ff = new FormField();
        ff.addField("username", new Validators() {
           int result = minLength(6);
        });
    }
```

And it is making use of anonymous derived class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a class instance as a parameter and define some value it'll use, you have to make this variable as attribute of the class and set it via the constuctor, like:

```
public class Validators {
    int l;

    public Validators(int l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    public int minLength() {
        // do something
        //here you can use l variable
    }
 }
```

And

```
public class FormField {
    public void addField(String field, Validators val) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
addField("username", new Validators(6)) {
...
```

And may be you have to take a look at [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)